# How can a malware site take control of Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, malware

I've had quite a scare today - the second time this month. I tried browsing to speedtest.net to test my connection, and I must have mistyped something (the last time that happened, I mistyped "google"). Next thing I know, a site with a big, bogus blue screen opened, it threw up a popup and started talking the popup's content repeatedly. The tab was showing the "play" icon, as if Flash was played in it. The domain was "virus--alert--warning.com", and the number is a known spammer (how are these allowed to a hvae an 800 number???).

[image]

It could not be stopped - the tab could not be closed, and I could't click the Chrome close button, or right-click it in the task bar and close it (Windows 10). I had to resort to killing it through task manager.

I'm a very careful user - no extensions in my browser (other than Disconnect, uBlock Origin, and 3 extensions I developed), I never install anything I don't know, open an email I don't recognize, or follow shady links etc.

I ran  Windows Defender, MalwareBytes and adwcleaner - all came up negative for malware or rootkits. Leaving me with my question: how can a website (using HTML, JS and probably Flash) create a situation where Chrome is stuck, repeatedly playing audio? Do I still have something on my computer that I missed, or was this done entirely in the browser?

Comment: Every single one of those windows are a browser dialog you understand right?  In other words, not a single message,is actually real.  I would say its safe to say, your not that protected, since Malwarebytes isn't blocking these dialogs like it normally does.

Comment: Of course I understand. I dismissed the content immediately (look at the typos, bogus content and number). I want to know how it was done, and did it leave permanent damage

Comment: No;  ALT+F4 will close any browser window.

Comment: Didn't work - had to Task Manager it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very unlikely that any damage has been made to your system, especially if none of those 3 antimalware programs reported anything strange. Also, keep in mind that Chrome's tabs are [sandboxed](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/sandbox) so it's hard (though [not impossible](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/07/hacking-teams-flash-0day-potent-enough-to-infect-actual-chrome-user/)) to alter a PC from the browser, if you haven't downloaded anything strange.

However, I was curious on how could a web freeze a browser, and found the [Fun Fun Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10966152), a ridiculously short JavaScript snippet that does exactly that, by just making the browser run out of memory. As stated by the author, its effects go from freezing the browser to **even crashing the whole operative system**.

At first I wondered what's the point (from a scammer POV) in making someone else's browser/computer stop working, but after reading the messages in your screenshot, I realized it's a very smart move: an unexperienced user could really think that his computer has been blocked by their ISP, Microsoft, the CIA or whoever else.
They call to get their computer *unblocked*, and I think we all know how this ends...

Comment: Great catch with the JavaScript. I was hoping the popup blocking in Chrome can prevent this from happening. Since the tab showed the "Flash playing" icon, I decide to also disable Flash in Chrome for good measure...

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy Yeah, that isn't a bad idea, either. As you may probably know, Flash is known to have multiple serious vulnerabilities (although many sites still use it).

Comment: @Hewbot Somewhat related - after some experimenting I was able to "crash" firefox by embedded a large image into the src ie - `src="data:image/gif;base64,{9 MB file}"`. It appears to be a known bug - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=822407 .